# installation of zend studio 8 in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, installation, zend-studio

When i try to install the zend studio it is not installing. Nothing happens if i click on the installation file. can you please give me the solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

First, check that you have the correct version: I'll presume you want just the IDE, not the whole Virtual Development Environment (which is a whole virtual machine image for use with VMware and such). The downloaded file should end with `.tar.gz` (not `.msi` nor `.dmg`).

Next, you'll want to unzip the archive file, which you can do either in the GUI (double-click to open the archive, click "Extract..." and choose a directory to unzip into), or via the shell (`tar zxvf filename.tar.gz`).

Then you'll go into the directory you just extracted and look for the "ZendStudio" program and double-click (GUI) or run by name (cd into the directory, type `ZendStudio` to run).

You may need to check that the program is executable; in the GUI you can change this by right-clicking on the file and editing the properties, or in the shell you can type `chmod +x ZendStudio`.

[Further directions are on this page in the Zend Studio guide](http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Studio/installing_zend_studio_on_linux.htm), but they're not very detailed. Hope that helps!